# How to deploy an app using external libraries In IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, dll, deployment, windows-server-2012-r2

This is my first time using IIS so I don't know much about how it works.

I developed an ASP.net c# web form app, in order to deploy it on a server using IIS. I had Visual Studio installed on the windows server, to make sure the app works fine, no problems up to this point.

When I publish the app from visual studio, and put the file system generated inside inetpub/wwwroot... the pages load fine but just when a I try feature of the app that needs an external library, an exception is raised exactly in the line where the first external library's object instaciated within the code (Information givven by the log).

I'm suspecting that once deployed on IIS app has no reference for the libraries or doesn't have the rights to access them since I haven't touched anything inside IIS besides adding the file system to the depault app pool. But how can I adress this issue?

Here are the two errors traces I got from my log :

```
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {ED0EC116-16B8-44CC-A68A-41BF6E15EB3F} failed due to the following error : 80070154 Class not registred (Exception  HRESULT : 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
```

Or Other Times:

```
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID  {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error : 80070005 Access Denied. (Exception  HRESULT : 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your app use Microsoft Office (Excel for example)?

Comment: @Kev 
Yes indeed, I am using it, but its library  is not he only one causing problem, all external libraries do.

Comment: What are all your external libraries?

Comment: Ok...first off please don't try and run Office products such as Excel as out-of-process COM servers in a web app. It's a terrible idea, they aren't designed for this and the experience always ends in tears. There are third party libraries that do this job better: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/how-do-i-create-an-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-in-c-sharp-without-installing-mic

Comment: @Kev actually the main ones are: 
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Objets100cLib
Objets100Lib
The two last ones are business objects libraries mage to work on a Entreprise ressource planning solution called Sage.
Coming to see it now, the features related to excel handling give me the com Access denied Error whereas the features related to business objects retur "class not registred error"

Answer (score 0):

The application is run on IIS base on the pool that you have assign it to it. This pool is run under a specific account.

So add this account to the DCOM Config to been able to access it.

First step is to find your pool user as.
[image]

Then add permissions for that user on your DCOM Applications so the pool can read them and run them.

To find the DCOM Config, go to

```
Control Panel | Administrative Tools | Component Services
```

Then open

```
Component Services | Computers | My Computer | DCOM Config
```

There find your applications that you use, left click to open the menu and select properties... there give permissions to your Pool user

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't encourage people to try an run Office products such as Excel as out-of-process COM servers in a web app. It's a terrible idea, they aren't designed for this and the experience always ends in tears. There are third party libraries that do this job better.

Comment: I have already tried that, I couldn't find the pool user, but I added in the permission the user: All users. I still get the same erros message.

Comment: Edit: 
I gave permission to all users but not only on the access permission, I did so on execution too, the objects seem to be instanciated, I'm goint to adress the other issues.
What about registering a Com component witch is the second error message I get?

Comment: @Kev 
I know that, I just need to unlock the current situation first befor writing a new code version with an other third part library.

Comment: @Marouane Maybe then you call some kind of program that needs user interface, or other libraries with user interface that can't be start - You can use Process Monitor from sysinternals to see whats going on. Also the permission to all, some time is not work "for all"...